# How to change the opacity of a surface out of a rectangular area?

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, clip

I made the following simple MWE to explain constrain function:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}‎‎[scale=1]
‎\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$‎, ‎ylabel=$y$‎, ‎zlabel={$z$}]‎‎
 \addplot3 ‎[‎‎surf‎, ‎samples=20‎, ‎domain=-4:4 ‎,‎‎color=gray!20,z buffer=auto] {4-x^2-y^2‎};‎‎
  \addplot3 [variable=t,domain=-2:2,black‎, ‎very thick‎, ‎samples y=0‎, ‎smooth]    ({t},{2},{-t^2});‎‎
  ‎\addplot3 [variable=t,domain=-2:2,black‎, ‎very thick‎, ‎samples y=0‎, ‎smooth] ({t},{-2},{-t^2});‎‎
  ‎\addplot3 [variable=t,domain=-2:2,black‎, ‎very thick‎, ‎samples y=0‎, ‎smooth] ({2},{t},{-t^2});‎‎
\addplot3 [variable=t,domain=-2:2,black‎, ‎very thick‎, ‎samples y=0‎, ‎smooth] ({-2},{t},{-t^2});‎
\end{axis}‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎‎‏‎‏‎
```

[image]

My question is: Can we change the transparency the area out of the rectangle on the surface a bit fade so we can explain the constrain functions by concentrating just a rectangular area? I don't want to remove the whole shape. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. And it is very simple if you increase the samples from 20 to 21.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel={$z$}]
 \addplot3 [surf, samples=21, domain=-4:4 ,color=gray!20,z
 buffer=auto,opacity=0.3] {4-x^2-y^2};
 \addplot3 [surf, samples=20, domain=-2:2 ,color=gray!20,z buffer=auto,
 samples=11,samples y=11] {4-x^2-y^2};
%   \addplot3 [variable=t,domain=-2:2,black, very thick, samples y=0, smooth]    ({t},{2},{-t^2});
%   \addplot3 [variable=t,domain=-2:2,black, very thick, samples y=0, smooth] ({t},{-2},{-t^2});
%   \addplot3 [variable=t,domain=-2:2,black, very thick, samples y=0, smooth] ({2},{t},{-t^2});
%   \addplot3 [variable=t,domain=-2:2,black, very thick, samples y=0, smooth] ({-2},{t},{-t^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the time. This is what I was looking for.